# Semantic error when attempting to find all prime numbers using Java

Tags: java

"Write a Boolean function that checks if a number is prime. Also implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm. Explain any optimizations made." I have a slight error as, when run, it states that 15,25,35,45 etc are also prime numbers, when in reality they are not. I have tried to alter the code in many ways but I still cannot manage to fix this issue. Could someone please help me?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question3 {

    public static boolean[] prime(int x) {
        boolean[] array = new boolean[x+1];
        Arrays.fill(array, true);
        lists(array);
        return array;
    }

    public static boolean PrimeNum (int x) {
        if (x < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int k = 2; k <= Math.sqrt(x); k++) {
            if (x% 2 == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else  {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void lists(boolean[] array) { //this method verifies if the number is a prime number or not
        array[0] = array[1] = false;
        int pNo = (int) Math.sqrt(array.length);
        for (int i = 2; i <= pNo; ++i) {
            if (array[i]) {
                // remove all multiples of this prime:
                for (int k = i*i;k<array.length;k = k+i) {
                    array[k] = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void display(boolean[] array) {
        for (int k = 2; k < array.length; ++k) { //array of 50 numbers
            if (array[k]) {
                System.out.print(k + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number to view all prime numbers up to it");
        int o = sc.nextInt();

        boolean r = PrimeNum(o);
        if(r == false) {
            System.out.println("Number inputted IS NOT a prime");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Number inputted IS a prime");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("The following are the prime numbers smaller than or equal to " + o);

        boolean [] array = prime(o);
        display(array);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every iteration checking x % 2 ==0 in if condition, this cant work becouse x is always same. You need to change it

Comment: It works well on my computer.
The following are the prime numbers smaller than or equal to 100
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97 
Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake:

```
for (int k = 2; k <= Math.sqrt(x); k++) {
    // other part of the code
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You should use: `x % k == 0` in the `if` condition and also remove the `else return true` part inside the `for` loop.

Comment: I have tried changing it to that and it still says that 15 is a prime when I input it. (Same goes with 25,35 etc.)

Comment: @Redent You should also delete the `else return true` part inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean PrimeNum(int x) {
    if (x < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(x);
    for (int k = 2; k <= sqrt; k++) {
        if (x % k == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For each `k`, check `x` is not a multiple of `k`. Only return true after the *whole loop* has finished without finding a factor.

Also, you don't need to recalculate the square root each turn through the loop.